# Is there a better way to remove stopwords in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, c, stop-words

The method I am doing right now is breaking the string into array of words in NSSet and minus the set of stopwords.  Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSRegularExpression is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for replying!  My suspicion was also NSRegularExpression, but the thought of matching a long string of word1|word2|word3... would still be efficient.  I will give it try, thanks Lee!

Comment: @unikorn: uses a single regex rather than a loop. They're compiled down to an efficient representation before matching, so will be faster than you'll manage with a for loop (which also has to do the compilation N times)

Comment: Yes.  After a few trial last night, I ended up with a string of 500+ words to regex and surprised to find it was really fast.  It parsed through roughly 100,000 lines of text in about 10 seconds.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A good regex library might do it faster.

Comment: you mean do a for loop and regex each term?